# Simple Text. Build doesn't work. What's wrong?

Tags: python, sublime-text

If I press build with following script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    class Strom(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.preis_kilowattstunde = 0.21


        def stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt):
            '''
            (integer) -> float 

            leitet aus einer Zahl in Watt eines Objektes die Stromkosten pro Jahr ab
            '''
            print(watt * brennstunden_im_tag * 365 * self.preis_kilowattstunde / 1000)

        def stromkosten_differenz(watt_objekt1, watt_objekt2):
            '''
            (integer, integer) -> float

            Nimmt die Stromkosten in Watt zweier Objekte und gibt die Stromkostendifferenz in CHF aus.
            '''
            if watt_objekt2 > watt_objekt1:
                print(stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt2) - stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt1))
            else:
                print(stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt1) - stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt2)
```

I get following error:

```
  File "/home/empedokles/Dropbox/Yannick/Python/stromkosten.py", line 31

         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/empedokles/Dropbox/Yannick/Python/stromkosten.py"]
[dir: /home/empedokles/Dropbox/Yannick/Python]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

Comment: @Seth: Thanks for the edit, but that wasn't what causes the error. The code button in that forum just won't work correctly on marked texts.

Comment: I wasn't suggested what caused the error. Code button worked fine for me.

Comment: @Seth: You duplicated parts of my code. The duplication isn't the problem.

Comment: I didn't duplicate any of your code, I just selected it and pressed the "code" button as you can see in the [revision history](http://askubuntu.com/posts/462566/revisions). Sorry if it somehow caused confusion. Maybe you accidentally pasted it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a closing `)` on the last line, so if you try to run your code as-is you'll get an error from that.

However, assuming you fix that, running this code with Python 3 will complete successfully, but will not give any output. You are defining a class and a couple of methods, but you never instantiate the class or call any of the methods. Even if you did, though, you'd get an error as `brennstunden_im_tag` is not defined anywhere, so you'll get an error trying to run `stromkosten_pro_jahr()`. You also need to have `self` as the first parameter for any class method. Finally, `stromkosten_pro_jahr()` should `return` the value, not `print()` it. Here is an example of what your code should look like:

```py
class Strom(object):
    def __init__(self, brennstunden_im_tag):
        self.preis_kilowattstunde = 0.21
        self.brennstunden_im_tag = brennstunden_im_tag

    def stromkosten_pro_jahr(self, watt):
        '''
        (integer) -> float

        leitet aus einer Zahl in Watt eines Objektes die Stromkosten pro Jahr ab
        '''
        return watt * self.brennstunden_im_tag * 365 * self.preis_kilowattstunde / 1000

    def stromkosten_differenz(self, watt_objekt1, watt_objekt2):
        '''
        (integer, integer) -> float

        Nimmt die Stromkosten in Watt zweier Objekte und gibt die Stromkostendifferenz in CHF aus.
        '''
        if watt_objekt2 > watt_objekt1:
            print(self.stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt2) - self.stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt1))
        else:
            print(self.stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt1) - self.stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_strom = Strom(10)
    my_strom.stromkosten_differenz(100, 50)
```

This returns `38.325` - hopefully that's the result you're looking for.

Comment: No, that is something intruduced by the one, who altered my posting. It's not the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: @user272441 The edit to your post did not change any of the code. Instead of using docstrings, try completely removing any bits of the code that you don't want to run, and try again.

Comment: @user272441 If the code in the question is not the code you are trying to run, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/462566/edit) the question and put in the correct code. Once you have pasted in your code, highlight it all and hit `Ctrl-K` to properly format it as a code block.

Comment: Okay, corrected.

Comment: @user272441 - please see my completely updated answer - this should solve your problems.

Comment: I still have an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/empedokles/Dropbox/Yannick/Python/stromkosten.py", line 28, in <module>
    my_strom.stromkosten_differenz(100, 50)
  File "/home/empedokles/Dropbox/Yannick/Python/stromkosten.py", line 24, in stromkosten_differenz
    return(stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt1) - stromkosten_pro_jahr(watt_objekt2))
NameError: global name 'stromkosten_pro_jahr' is not defined
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/empedokles/Dropbox/Yannick/Python/stromkosten.py"] ...

Comment: Now everything's fine. I accidentally used return with parentesis ().

Comment: @user272441 that's good - The code I posted runs perfectly in both Python 2.7.6 and 3.3.5. What may have happened is you copied and pasted the code, but forgot to save before building, and it built the previous version.

Comment: Is there a way to have IDLEs >>> interactivity in sublime text?

Comment: @user272441 - yes, there is. If you haven't already, please install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation), then install [`SublimeREPL`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeREPL).

Comment: I installed it, it opens in a new window over tools/command-palette.. sublimeREPL:Python. How do I run my file from there?

Comment: @user272441 - you can read through the [README](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#readme), and also browse through the `Tools -> SublimeREPL` menus for the different options available.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably install a [linter](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/pylint) package to see what's wrong with your code, obviously the problem is in your code.